# How to create 1-bits bitmaps using BufferedImage object?

Tags: java, bitmap

I'm trying to obtain a **1-bits** bitmap's RGB, put it in a multidimensional array to perform some tasks and recreate the bitmap again to its original form. 
Although almost the same code worked just fine with 4-bits and 8-bit bitmaps my end result shows a black image for the 1-bits bitmaps, not really sure of what I've done wrong here!!
Thanks in advance.

```
BufferedImage in = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\SourceImage.bmp"));
int w = in.getWidth(), h = in.getHeight();
int[][] array = new int[w][h];
for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < h; k++) {
        array[j][k] = in.getRGB(j, k);
    }
}

// perform operations on array[ ][ ]

byte[] v = new byte[2];
for (int i = 0; i < v.length; ++i) {
    v[i] = (byte) (i );
}
ColorModel cm = new IndexColorModel(1, v.length, v, v, v);
WritableRaster wr = cm.createCompatibleWritableRaster(w, h);
BufferedImage out = new BufferedImage(cm, wr, false, null);
for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        int Pixel = array[x][y] << 16 | array[x][y] << 8 | array[x][y];
        out.setRGB(x, y, array[x][y]);
    }
}
Graphics2D g = out.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(out, 0, 0, null);
g.dispose();
ImageIO.write(out, "bmp", new File("D:\\ResultImage.bmp"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your values for `v` need to be 0 and 255, not 0 and 1. Otherwise you'll get an image with dark values RGB(0, 0, 0) and light values RGB(1, 1, 1) which appears to be all black.

```
byte[] v = {(byte) 0, (byte) 0xff};
```